# How to include service principals in the list members of directoryroles?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get lists of members of all available directory roles using **GET /directoryRoles/[ROLE_ID]/members** query. This query is returning all the users but skipping all service principals that have admin roles.
My app has *Directory.Read.All* application permission; my understanding was that it should be enough to retrieve any directory objects.

Is it a known bug or is there any workaround to include the service principals in the list of role members?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As we can see in the properties of the directory roles, there is no property that mentions the service principle:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/directoryrole?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

Answer (score 1):

use the beta endpoint to retrieve service principal objects:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/directoryRoles/{role-id}/members](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/directoryRoles/%7Brole-id%7D/members)